# stanford coreNLP coreference error

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am using `stanford-corenlp-3.3.1`, same code as given in URL (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Download) but got following error:

```
Adding annotator tokenize Adding annotator ssplit Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.stanford.nlp.process.WordToSentenceProcessor.stringToNewlineIsSentenceBreak(Ljava/lang/String;)Ledu/stanford/nlp/process/WordToSentenceProcessor$NewlineIsSentenceBreak;
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.WordsToSentencesAnnotator.(WordsToSentencesAnnotator.java:55)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$3.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:520)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:81)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:262)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:129)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:125)
at utils.Coref.main(Coref.java:32)
```

it shows error at

```
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```

Any help and suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: ssplit only works in conjunction with `"-tokenize.whitespace true"`. Try to take "ssplit" out: `props.put("annotators", "tokenize, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");`

Comment: Then pos, lemma.... etc requires ssplit. \n Thanks for reply.

Comment: SOLVED: That was due to older version of Stanford packages (for eg. in my other package I am using NER). So I removed it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great explanation of this general condition [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp-faq.shtml).  This kind of condition is always because there are multiple versions of corenlp artifacts lying around somewhere on your runtime classpath.  It could be obvious, it could be hidden.  You really have to cross your fingers that it will not take you too long to find out where the wrong classes or methods are being loaded.

As an example, I got the exact same error message as the OP and I found I had a jar file called seg.jar that somehow crept into my project and so I removed that and it solved the problem.